# I am trying to find the render output node

Tags: rendering, node-editor

I use Blender for 3D printing but now need it for actual rendering CAD/Patent style renders but really struggling.
I'm trying to render an image using nodes but after switching to the compositor and adding the nodes from a tutorial I get an error saying there isn't a render output node in the scene. I have looked for the composite node in the "Add/Output/Composite" but that's not there. I have tried the only output nodes available and still get the same error. Any help is greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, it looks like you are looking for a Compositor node but you are in the Shader Editor, not in the Compositor

Comment: @moonboots that is exactly the issue, he says he switched to the Compositor but he actually switched to the Shader editor.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently in the *Shader Editor*, switch your window to *Compositor*.

Comment: Well, if "he" is in the shader editor, he must be digital. Well in 2054 this is possible but i don't think this is possible in 2022...so please be precise: His Blender window is in type "Shader editor" :D but +1 for trying to answer something... :D and because you need the reputation to become No.1  not least in one thing...

Comment: hey Chris, thanks for the reputation, I want to be the Kim Kardashian of BSE